# How to deal with URL in browser which is changed to form action value after wrong data is submitted?

Tags: forms, http, grails, web-applications, language-agnostic

*The question is generally language/framework agnostic but if it matters I work with Grails and most interested in grails specific solution if such exists.*

There's a form mapped to URL: `/foo/create`. When user type in this URL to his browser the form is shown.

Form action attribute directs to `/foo/save` and has method `POST`. If saving is successful, then standard post-redirect-get pattern is applied, and user is redirected to `/foo/show`.

But, if user specified incorrect data, they should see the same form again with error messages and all their data preserved. To implement this behavior, I do `forward` to the controller which produces the form (the same is mapped to `/foo/create`).

After that user sees the form with data and error messages, but URL field is changed in browser to `/foo/save`. And if user change focus to URL field and press enter - 404 will be shown (because nothing is mapped to `/foo/save` + `method=GET` pair).

**The long story short**: URL `/foo/save` is shown in a browser (as there were no redirection after form was submitted) but it directs to nowhere if accessed by HTTP GET method.

How to deal with this situation? Surely, I can map something to `/foo/save` but I wonder if there's a way not to change URL shown in a browser after form with wrong data was submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. The form submits to itself, i.e. `/foo/create` submits to `/foo/create`, only if successful the page is redirected to `/foo/show`. This *should* use a post-redirect-get cycle as well and store the submitted data in the session, but *could* be a simple POST without redirect.
2. `/foo/save` *always* redirects again, either to `/foo/create` if the data was invalid or to `/foo/show` if the data was valid. This will always use a post-redirect-get cycle with the data saved in the session.